# How to get the method name of a getter on JavaScrpt?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get programatically the name of a getter method on Javascript?

For example:

```js
class Example {
  methodA() {}
  get methodB() {}
}

console.log('works', Example.prototype.methodA.name);
console.log('fails', Example.prototype.methodB.name);
```

I want to do that because I am using a Proxy to handle an extension of a class and want to detect when the getter method is called.

Sure I can use:

```
if (prop === 'methodB')
```

But then, case the method is renamed I/anyone else will have to remember to rename the if checks. **Example.prototype.methodA.name** is always updated.

Comment: "*Example.prototype.methodA.name is always updated.*" not necessarily. Check `const obj = { foo: function bar() {} }; console.log(obj.foo.name);`

Comment: But then you are creating a diffrent object. Not just extracting the name of the method from the prototype. I am not getting the name of the method from instances. I am getting it from the prototype of the class.

Comment: You think `class Obj { foo = function bar() {} }` behaves any different? Or `Obj.prototype.foo = function bar() {}` if you really wish to get it from the prototype?

Comment: "*I am using a Proxy to handle an extension of a class*" - it's not clear what you're trying to achieve there. But probably you neither need the proxy nor the name of the getter. Can you show us the code of the proxy please?

Comment: The code is long..  it is the way I am doing to build trees of HTMLElements.  I created a class HTMLElementProxy extends HTMLElement  so that I can pass extra methods, like "._add(...)", "_addHtml(..)",  the issue was with "get _target()",  could make it a function, but  as a method had this issue of having to write the name "_target" to check it on the proxy,  when I want to get the original object and not the proxy on the functions I use to create the layout..

Comment: Well sure I could encapsulate the HTMLElement on another class instead of using a proxy for it, but this is not havng any performance issue, then it is just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the method by using :

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop).get.name
```

Example:

```js
class Example {
  methodA() {}
  get methodB() {}
}

const methodBGetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Example.prototype, 'methodB').get;
console.log(methodBGetter.name);
```

console.log will be `"get methodB"`.

Comment: This does "work", but is rather pointless if you have to pass in the name of the property as a string to get out the name the property as a string.

Comment: Yes, thanks Barmar for the answer, showing what is possible to do, but agree with Bergi.